# How to activate a second power after the first one is turned on?

Tags: power-supply, power

There are 2 different power sources and are not connected to each other. How is it possible to turn the second on after the first one is activated?

PS: if the first power is off, the second power may be off to preserve the electricity.

Edit: The power supply is battery in a DC circuit, 12V, 2A

Comment: What are these power sources? Are they power supplies? Or AC power, like utility power or a generator? Or are they regulators on a small circuit board? Anyway, you will need to add some kind of connection between them to achieve your goal. But you need to provide a lot more information.

Comment: So is the question just, turn B on when A is on? This is pretty standard and usually a relay would be used. However, as mentioned, specifics in terms of AC/DC, current and voltage are required information.

Comment: Ditto.  Need more information and a specific question that can attract useful answers.

Comment: Sorry, I forget that part. The power supply is battery in a DC circuit, 12V, 2A

Comment: The battery is ONE source, now it is clear. What is the other "not connected" and different source? And I still hope that they have a common ground.

Comment: They're 2 batteries with the same specs but diffrent ground

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by grounds not connected together?

Comment: Would it be possible/acceptable to connect the grounds together? If so, a simple PMOS switch will do what you want. If the grounds must be kept separate, I would look at either a relay, or a PMOS switch controlled by an opto-isolator. For 12V, 2A, PMOS switches are viable, so you can do high-side switching.

Answer (score 2):

Most of modern power regulators have a pin that enables/disables them. Usually the enable is logic positive, so a HIGH level enables them. Usually this control input has high impedance, so resistors of 50-100k works just fine.

To provide the power-up in sequence, A first, B next, you just need to connect the enable pin on PSU-B via a R-C circuit to power rail A. The capacitor will provide certain delay from A to B.

If you don't have the EN pin on your PSU-B, then you should change your controller IC, otherwise the power-off circuit would require some high-side FET with extra control circuitry in front of the PSU-B, which could be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

> There are 2 different power sources and are not connected to each
>   other. How is it possible to turn the second on after the first one is
>   activated?

Use an electromechanical relay with a normally closed (NC) contact. The NC contact is in series with the 2nd power source and, when power source 1 is active (and thus driving the realy coil) it interrupts the 2nd power source and prevents it powering its load. When the first power source is inactive, the 2nd power source is connected to its load.